# Android: Overriding shared element return animation

Tags: android, animation, transition, element

Here's my situation:

I have Fragment a with a recycler view. Each item has a TextView and an ImageView icon thumbnail. When pressed the app will open up the detail view for this item.

I'm trying to use a shared element with reveal transition starting from the icon thumbnail on the recycler view item to the header image of the detail view. This works, **but i don't want the animation to return like it started**.

When the user pressed the back button the animation will happen in reverse. I'm trying to override this with the regular default slide transition but I have not succeeded.

What I have tried so far:

```
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/no_transition</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/no_transition</item>
```

I've also tried to override onBackPressed and onPause on the detail activity, but it doesn't seem to work and the animation still happens.

Is there anything i'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the **return** transition (else by default it will reverse the enter transition):

```
<item name="android:windowSharedElementReturnTransition">@transition/your_transition</item>
```

Read more here: https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/what-are-all-these-dang-transitions/